Unable to load library 'libSkiaSharp' - skiaSharp
I am new in MAUI ..
MAUI installed in visual studio 2022 but when I run emulator or build (rebuild) project I have this error

Unable to load library 'libSkiaSharp'

I tried more and more and I failed to load it ...

Pakages are installed

skiaSharp pakages are installed

Maui is the second largest of the Hawaiian islands, I'm sure that's not what you mean. Please, nobody here knows or can guess your context. So, take the [tour] and read [ask] and then rework your question.

Thanks for your replay but this community for asking question and resolvin problems it is not the first time I asked here .. If I do not know how to solve this problem where can I search ...

@UlrichEckhardt bit weird comment. MAUI (Multi-platform App UI) is a well known cross-platform UI framework in the .NET space. What is .NET MAUI

I'd suggest adding a tag for .Net and one for the programming language, then.

@jitter I am nit asking what is MAUI    Ulrich Eckhardt and I am not asking how to ask here ... My question is how to resolve this problem ... Simply I can not add or load the library libskiaSharp that's it

You don't have to install the all packages. You can just install the package SkiaSharp version 2.88 and then run your project.
In you second picture, you installed the other platforms package in the android part of the project. You can remove them and only keep the special platform package.
If you choose only use package SkiaSharp version 2.88. You can see the following code in the csproj file:
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.88.8" />
</ItemGroup>

If you use both package SkiaSharp version 2.88 and special platform package, you can see the following code in your project's csproj file:
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.88.8" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
  <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Android">
    <Version>2.88.8</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-ios'">
  <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.iOS">
    <Version>2.88.8</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-maccatalyst'">
  <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.macOS">
    <Version>2.88.8</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

I didn't find the special package for windows platform. Maui's windows part is based on WinUI 3.

Thanks for your responed but I have the same error  when I  am instaling the pakage

Did you only install the SkiaSharp 2.8.8? Did you try to clean and rebuild? It can build successfully in my project. @MUHAMMEDDÖNMEZ

Yes I did it and I saw this code :
*<ItemGroup>       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />       <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.88.8" /> </ItemGroup>*
and I have the same error when clean and build and rebuild and when instaling pakage ..

After this, did the other packages such as SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.iOS disappeared? In addition, did you try to create a new project and test the package again? @MUHAMMEDDÖNMEZ

Yes disappeared,, I create a new project and the same problem !!!

I tried again and it can work well in my project. You can try to update the Visual Studio. @MUHAMMEDDÖNMEZ

In addition, you can try to add both SkiaSharp and SkiaSharp.Views package. @MUHAMMEDDÖNMEZ

Visual Studio. is updatetd alsoo I installed the SkiaSharp.Views and the same
Can we make a connection like whatsapp or somthing if you don't mind

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/25208

I didn't see the smallest sample project in the link. Could you please provide a sample? @MUHAMMEDDÖNMEZ
